# Copy SharePoint Online site to a different Microsoft 365 subscription

Tags: sharepoint-online, migration

Apart from third-party paid options (such as ShareGate), is there a way to copy an entire SharePoint site with all document libraries and lists to another Microsoft 365 Subscription? The SharePoint size can be over 500MB in size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order not to have impact on your business, it is currently still recommended to migrate SharePoint Online sites to another tenant using 3rd party tools.

The OOTB Cross-Tenant User Content Migration feature and licenses are currently only available to Enterprise Agreement customers.

If you are an Enterprise Agreement customer who will be purchasing Cross-Tenant User Content Migration licenses, and you would like to evaluate Cross-Tenant SharePoint migration to improve your migration experience, sign-up at:

https://aka.ms/ODSPSecurityPreviews
Make sure to include all of the requested information, and indicate your interest in "SharePoint cross-tenant data migration (Mergers and Acquisition scenario)".

See this article for more information: [Cross-tenant SharePoint migration (preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/cross-tenant-sharepoint-migration?view=o365-worldwide).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are several ways to copy a SharePoint site with all its content to another Microsoft 365 subscription without using third-party paid options. Here are a few options:

- Use the `"Save as Template"` feature: You can save the site as a template with content, and then use the template to create a new site in the destination Microsoft 365 subscription. This method has some limitations, such as a file size limit of 50MB and a list view threshold limit of 5,000 items. To save a site as a template, go to Site Settings > Site Actions > Save site as template.
- Use the `"Site Collection Backup"` feature: You can create a backup of the entire site collection, including all subsites, lists, and libraries, and restore it to the destination Microsoft 365 subscription.
- Use the `"PnP Provisioning"` feature: You can use the SharePoint Patterns and Practices (PnP) Provisioning engine to copy the entire site to another Microsoft 365 subscription.

Note that all these methods require appropriate permissions to the source and destination sites. Additionally, these methods may not copy certain features or configurations, such as custom solutions or workflows, so you may need to recreate them manually in the destination site.

Comment: thanks for your reply. In my case, I need to copy from one Microsoft  tenant to another. The "Save as Template" is not suitable because of the size limit. Using the "Site Collection Backup" , is it possible to backup a SharePoint site from a Microsoft 365 tenant and restore it on another tenant? I checked "PnP Provisioning", but I cannot find scripts for copying sites including their full content. Could you please share any links?